# FlexSlider stutter/lag on fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

I am using Flexslider (the older version 1.0 with jquery 1.4.8 support) on the following test page: http://www.showstyle.lu/service/startv2/

As you can see the slider is implemented on the top left and bottom right images (in the upper part of the content). When I test this offline through dreamweaver there are no stutter effects or lag effects but in chrome/firefox/opera the fade effect begins but then rushes into the next slide in a quite awkward fashion.

It doesn't look smooth, in IE it doesn't fade at all but that's ok, it's IE afterall (rip IE)

I looked through Stackoverflow and plenty pages on google people mention that it is a float related issue across Firefox mainly and not many occurences in Chrome.

I looked through my sliders and inspected them & unticked various classes in the css to see if it would impact the fluidity of the slider but no luck so far so I can't really pinpoint the code that is interfering with the slider.

Any experience dealing with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but in your style.css you have this bit of code for slider transition:

```
* {
-moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
transition: color 0.3s ease;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; */
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out; */
```

}

By removing the bottom 3 properties I was able to get a *much* smoother transition on your slider (did this by inspecting the element and editing CSS). Therefore, if this section of your CSS was just this:

```
* {
-moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
transition: color 0.3s ease;
```

I think you'll get the smoother transition you're looking for. (This was done in Chrome, and have not tested other browsers).

Comment: Great, glad I can help! I'm not sure if you're familiar with the 'inspect element' tool on browsers, but it can be very helpful for checking/editing CSS! right-click + insspect element will show the code and CSS on the page, you can then edit the CSS in the inspection window, and it'll change on the page, however, this will not affect the actual file.

Comment: Nah I actually am very well versed with that, it's what I use to troubleshoot the website since it runs on a pretty awkward unknown CMS platform so the style.css sheet for instance was written by them - all my code is well coincided and efficient. I did use it to try and figure this one but I seemed to be unable to find the correlating error, thanks for the heads up anyways :) !